# How can i deploy java project in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, project

I got java project, that can scheduling the task. It will print every job that has been done on logging. How can i deploy on my local (maybe with tomcat) and and view logs for each work that has been done by it?

Im using Spring Boot. I created Executeable JAR file and how can i deploy it? without IDE..

Comment: It's bit vague question. Are you creating JAR file, WAR file etc? If it's local only why don't you just run using IDE? Please be clear.

Comment: If you have a `war` file, you can just copy it into Tomcat's `webapps` directory. See [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Deployment_With_Tomcat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have web dependency on class path you get tomcat support along with it so you could
just run following command on console

> java -jar yourjarfilename.jar